# Local JSON data to getJSON on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am using this script which reads some internal json data.

The data is currently in the actual page.

I need to change the code to use getJSON? so that it reads the json from an external page/url

Here is the current full code:

```
<script>

var data = [{"id": "1","title": "mytitle"}];

  var output = '';

 $.each(data, function(index, value){
        output += '<li data-icon="false"><a href="#">' + value.title + '</a></li>';
    });


    $('#listview').append(output).listview('refresh');

</script>
```

How do I change the code so I can use external json code instead of this way for example adding getJSON to it?

Comment: Sorry, now updated: How do I change the code so I can use external json code instead of this way for example adding getJSON to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('url_to_script', function(data) {
  var output = '';
  $.each(data, function(index, value){
    output += '<li data-icon="false"><a href="#">' + value.title + '</a></li>';
  });
  $('#listview').append(output).listview('refresh');
});
```

But if you're trying to get data from different domain then you need something following:

```
$.getJSON("url_to_script?jsoncallback=?",, function(data) {
  var output = '';
  $.each(data, function(index, value){
    output += '<li data-icon="false"><a href="#">' + value.title + '</a></li>';
  });
  $('#listview').append(output).listview('refresh');
});
```

Read more about **[.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)**.